# Need help creating reg-ex expression to rewrite path and filename using information in original path and file name

Tags: regex, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I wish to redirect the link to my images in my image database to a cached copy of the watermarked images.   My scripting program that runs my site reconstructs the watermarked file name using the subfolder name where the image is located and appending the original filename (.jpg), with a tilde at the beginning of each of the two components of the reconstructed file name.

Example:
Original file located here:
`/mainFolder_files/1/image_Category/102_3456-crop.jpg`
New path should be:
`/mainFolder_files/cache/images/~image_Category~102_3456-crop.jpg`

The image file name usually includes underscores, hypens, numbers and text, but always ends in .jpg.  The "image_Category" folder may or may not include underscores.

Can anyone suggest the reg-ex that would capture the original data and rewrite it in a modified fashion as shown?

This is a CGI script driven program, so help with the Mod-Rewrite syntax would also be helpful.

Thank you,
Art Minds

Comment: If you first make an attempt yourself and then post what you tried and how it failed, you will be more likely to find help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(ImageFolio4_files)/1/([^/]+)/((?!AM|tn_)[^.]+\.jpg)$ /$1/cache/images/~$2~$3 [L,R=302,NC]
```

Once you verify it is working fine, replace `R=302` to `R=301`. Avoid using `R=301` (Permanent Redirect) while testing your mod_rewrite rules.

Comment: Thank you @anubhava so much.  I had to make the following changes but now it works flawlessly.   `^ImageFolio4_files/1/([^/]+)/([^.]+\.jpg)$ http://www.artminds.com/ImageFolio4_files/cache/images/~$1~$2 [L,R=301,NC]`  I didn't add `RewriteBase /` Can you please tell me what that adds?

Comment: Hello @anubhava .   I've also discovered another problem however. Unless this redirect EXCLUDES files that begin with tn_ or AM it breaks other portions of my scripting program. Can you suggest code that will redirect only if those two prefixes are not present?  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hello @anubhava . I tried this code and it seems to work to exclude redirecting .jpg files that being with tn_ or AM. Can you tell me if you see any problem with it?  `RewriteRule ^ImageFolio4_files/1/([^/]+?)(tn_|AM)/([^.]+\.jpg)$ http://www.artminds.com/ImageFolio4_files/cache/images/~$1~$2 [L,R=301,NC]`

Comment: Your code will only work for filenames starting from AM or tn_ . I thought you wanted to exclude them for redirection.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your edit from 45 minutes ago.  Let me try that.  I do want to exclude those prefixes from the rewrite.

Comment: I discovered that I also need to accomodate a second folder level in the redirect, which is also separated only by a tilde~.  The solution you provided works subject to the slight modification I had to make:  `RewriteRule ^ImageFolio4_files/1/([^/]+)/((?!AM|tn_)[^.]+\.jpg)$ /ImageFolio4_files/cache/images/~$1~$2 [L,R=302,NC]`  Can you suggest how to add that possible second folder level (but have it be optional if it is only one folder deep?

Comment: Please excuse my multiple comments, but I now realized that I must accomodate up to three folder levels in the original path to be rewritten, for example: `ImageFolio4_files/1/Model_Portfolios/Nico/Fashion/100_0982.jpg` The rewritten path would look like this: `ImageFolio4_files/cache/~Model_Portfolios~Nico~Fashion~100_0982.jpg`  I can't thank you enough for your gracious contribution of time to helping me solve this. I'm new to Regex and it's not the easiest concept to master.

Comment: To be honest I think I had answered original posted problem very first time itself. If you like me to answer a different nature of the problem then please post a new question on SO and I will happily provide an answer to the best of my abilities.

Comment: THank you, I'll post a new question. I understand what you are saying that you think you solved it the first time, by making (ImageFolio4_files) variable $1.  But that doesn't need to be a variable, because that doesn't change.  The potential for multiple folder levels occurs further down the path, after /cache/images/(multiple folder levels separated by ~)~filename.jpg.